# How to change all values to the left of a particular cell in every row

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array which contains 1's and 0's. A very small section of it looks like this:

```
arr=[[0,0,0,0,1], 
     [0,0,1,0,0],
     [0,1,0,0,0],
     [1,0,1,0,0]]
```

I want to change the value of every cell to 1, if it is to the left of a cell with a value of 1. I want all other cells to keep their value of 0, i.e:

```
arrOut=[[1,1,1,1,1], 
     [1,1,1,0,0],
     [1,1,0,0,0]
     [1,1,1,0,0]
```

Some rows have >1 cell with a value =1.

I have managed to do this using a very ugly double for-loop:

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
    for j in range(len(arr[i])):
        if arr[i][j]==1:
            arrOut[i][0:j]=1
```

Does anyone know of another way to do this with using for loops? I'm relatively comfortable with numpy and pandas, but also open to other libraries.

Thanks!

Comment: Do all lists have at least a 1? Can they have more than a 1?

Comment: All rows have at least one cell =1, some have >1 cell with value =1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can flip using it, and use `np.cumsum`:

```
>>> arr[:, ::-1].cumsum(axis=1)[:, ::-1]
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

Or the same using `np.fliplr`,

```
>>> np.fliplr(np.fliplr(arr).cumsum(axis=1))
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

Using `np.where`:

```
>>> np.where(arr.cumsum(1)==0, 1, arr)
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

If array has more than one `1`, use `np.clip`:

```
>>> arr
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]])

>>> np.clip(arr[:, ::-1].cumsum(axis=1)[:, ::-1], 0, 1)
 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]], dtype=int32)

# If you want to make all 0s before the leftmost 1 to 1:
>>> np.where(arr.cumsum(1)==0, 1, arr)

array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 0]])
```

Comment: Thank you, this works when I only have one cell in every row =1. There are some occasions where there are > 1 cells = 1 in a row. Apologies I should have made this clear in my original question (I have edited the question to make this clear).

I can overcome this by using 

arrOut=np.where(arrOut>1,1,0). 

If you know of another work around, where I don't have to use this second step, I would be interested in knowing!

Comment: The second last code block, that uses `np.clip` should address this.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility without using libraries:

```
for subarray in arr:
    #Get the index of the 1 starting from behind so that if there are 2 1s, 
    #you get the index of the rightmost one
    indexof1 = len(subarray) -1 - subarray[::-1].index(1)
    #Until the 1, replace with 1s 
    subarray[:indexof1] = [1]*len(subarray[:indexof1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using `np.maximum.accumulate`:

```
np.maximum.accumulate(arr[:,::-1],axis=1)[:,::-1]
```

Where `np.maximum.accumulate` simply apply a cumulative maximum (cummax).